# Excel Workbook compile error after calling sub

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, compiler-errors

I'm trying to make a worksheet of dynamically generated checkboxes, so I made the below sub to re-name them so I would be able to refer to them later (since I get what the checkboxes are representing from another sub and can't hardcode there names in). It works fine, however it seems to be the cause of a strange error I'm getting. After I run the main sub in my macro I get a compile error whenever I try to run any macro's. The exact error is:

> Compile error:
>       Object library invalid or contains references to object definitions that could not be found

This is an error that a bunch of other people have got but none seem to be in the same circumstances and none of the suggested fixes have worked for me.

In the actual macro reNameCheckBox1 (the class that seems to be causing the issue) is ran numerous times but when ran only once no problem occurs.

The problem class:

```
Sub reNameCheckBox1(newName As String, mainWB As Workbook)

Dim obj As OLEObject
Dim i As Integer



    i = 1

With mainWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

For Each obj In .OLEObjects
Debug.Print obj.name

If TypeName(obj.Object) = "CheckBox" And Left(obj.name, 8) = "CheckBox" Then
Debug.Print "Found it"

obj.name = newName

mainWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects(newName).Object.Caption = newName
Exit For
End If
Next obj
i = i + 1

End With

End Sub
```

How its called used when its causing problems:

```
For n = 1 To numberOfNames

mainWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1",       Link:=False, _
    DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=48, Top:=checkBoxTop, Width:=96, Height:=30). _
    Select

Call reNameCheckBox1("Name=" & arrayOfNames(n), mainWB)

checkBoxTop = checkBoxTop + 45



Next n
```

If anyone knows why this is causing problems or a better way to do what I'm trying to do it would be MUCH appreciated.

EDIT

As per comintern's suggestion, how the arrayOfNames is inilialized is shown below. Just a few things to note. 1) searchForParameters returns two lists, which i'll ill call arrayOfNames and otherNames, and in an attempt to return them both I stored them in one comfusingly organized array. 2) I didn't know LBound or UBound existed when I made this (i'm new to vba) and 3) results is organized as such, 
-At zero the length of the entire results array is stored
-At one the length of arrayOfNames
-at the beginning of OtherNames its length is stored

So, taking that confusing mess and turning into arrayOfNames and otherNames looks like this.

```
Dim results As Variant
Dim arrayOfNames As String
Dim otherNames As String
Dim length as Integer
Dim arrayOfNamesLength as Integer
Dim otherNamesLength As Integer
Dim n, i As Integer
results = searchForParameters(currentWB) 'Current wb is the name of the wb   its searching, which isnt the one the code's being ran out of

length = results(0)
arrayOfNamesLength = results(1)
otherNamesLength = results (arrayOfNamesLength + 2)
ReDim arrayOfNames(arrayOfNamesLength + 1)
ReDim otherNames(otherNamesLength)

For i = 0 To arrayOfNamesLength
arrayOfNames(i) = results(i + 1)
Next i

For n = 0 To otherNamesLength
OtherNames(n) = results(i + n + 1)
Next n
```

EDIT
As it turns out, the compile error this question was created to solve was not caused by any of the code here, but by a separate class. So if your having the same error I'm having, the solution won't be here. Since it has some really good answers on fixing the code I did have, I guess I'll just leave this here and hope someone finds it useful.
Cheers
-Ben J. Man

Answer (score 3):

It's unclear whether your **arrayOfNames** has a one-based or zero-based index. I suspect the former. Use the [LBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a7w1ac(v=vs.90).aspx)
[UBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278658.aspx) functions to define the scope of your array elements.

I am also suspect of the quoted 'named parameter'. You can use named parameters but not in that manner.

```
For n = LBound(arrayOfNames) To UBound(arrayOfNames)

    mainWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1",       Link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=48, Top:=checkBoxTop, Width:=96, Height:=30). _
        Select

    reNameCheckBox1 newName:=CStr(arrayOfNames(n)), mainWB:=mainWB

    checkBoxTop = checkBoxTop + 45

Next n
```

I'm not sure that the [Workbook Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835568.aspx) [Application.Selection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840834.aspx) property needs to be used like that. I recommend simply referring to the Workbook object as a parameter.

You might get a problem passing a variant element of a variant array as a string type parameter so I've cast it as a string.

`Call` isn't necessary and some people think it is antiquated. Use it if you like; it does no harm.

Comment: The `Select` isn't being called on `mainWB` - it's being called on the return value of `OLEObjects.Add` (which would be the new CheckBox).

Comment: That's right; good catch! But is a selected object necessary at all if it isn't being passed to the renaming procedure?

Comment: Nope - in fact it isn't even used. It might move the viewer pane down when it's run, but that's about it.

Comment: Well I've made the changes you've suggest and its all working well and the checkboxes are all made and named but I'm still getting the compile error on any other macros I try to make afterwords. Also once again sorry for the late response

Comment: Essentially you are creating an object and at the moment of creation, you know what it is. You then forget what it is and pass control to a helper routine that loops through all of the objects in the worksheet looking for the object you forgot a couple of code lines ago. My suggestions were geared at fixing your existing problems but Comintern's code is simply a better way of doing things. I would suggest abandoning your current methodology in favour of the other.

Comment: I did abandon the the reNameCheckBox1 method entirely and use comintern's methodology, but I also casted to string as you suggested and changed how I was looping as you both suggested. However unfortunately I'm still getting that odd compile error which is the biggest problem.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't exactly clear why you are selecting the CheckBox returned from `OLEObjects.Add` and then immediately searching for it in `reNameCheckBox1`. Just grab a reference and rename it in your loop:

```
Dim cb As OLEObject
For n = LBound(arrayOfNames) To UBound(arrayOfNames)
    Set cb = mainWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects.Add( _
                    ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1", _
                    Link:=False, _
                    DisplayAsIcon:=False, _
                    Left:=48, _
                    Top:=checkBoxTop, _
                    Width:=96, _
                    Height:=30)
    cb.Name = arrayOfNames(n)
    cb.Object.Caption = arrayOfNames(n)
    checkBoxTop = checkBoxTop + 45
Next n
```

Comment: I might have use `With ...Add` but this is a much better approach.

Comment: This is certainly more efficient and thanks for showing me this but unfortunately my problem with the compile error still exists.  I haven't tried Jeeped's fixes yet though so I'll comment again soon with the results from that.

Comment: P.S. Sorry for super late response I had to leave my computer right after asking and didn't get a chance to try either fix until now.

Comment: @BenJ.Man - I'm guessing it has to do with the contents of `arrayOfNames` then.  Can you update the question with the initialization of that array?

Comment: Done. That wouldn't surprise me actually I ended up doing some weird stuff with arrayOfNames

Comment: @BenJ.Man - That's odd - the code you posted shouldn't even compile.  `Dim arrayOfNames As String` should be `Dim arrayOfNames() As String`, same for `otherNames`. Unless your arrays are `Variant()` or `Variant`, anything you add to them should be implicitly cast to a `String`.

Comment: Oops, yeah they have the () in my code, I just forgot to put them in the edit.

Comment: @BenJ.Man - I'm thinking you have a scope issue then. Do you have `Option Explicit` at the top of your module?

Comment: Yeah, at the top above all the actual subs